# Transform BeautifulSoup extract into sqlite table

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a html table structure that looks something like:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul>
                </ul
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table>  -- (table structure I am interested in)
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="dte"></td>
                            <td class="id"></td>
                            <td class="desc"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="dte"></td>
                            <td class="id"></td>
                            <td class="desc"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="dte"></td>
                            <td class="id"></td>
                            <td class="desc"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

using python/BeautifulSoup, I have managed to print an output to screen like:-

```
[b'16 March', b'987654', b'Something happens on this date']
[b'23 March', b'321987', b'Something happens on this date']
[b'26 March', b'123456', b'Something happens on this date']
```

using the following code (which I have hacked together from various posts on this site):-

```
for mytable in soup.find('body').find_all('table'):
        #print (len(mytable))
        for trs in mytable.find_all('tr'):
            tds = trs.find_all('td', class_='dte id desc'.split())

            if tds: # checks if 'tds' has value.  if YES then block is executed
                row = [elem.text.strip().encode('utf-8') for elem in tds]
                print (row)

            else:
                continue # 'row' item is empty, proceed to next loop
```

2 questions:

1. when the output prints to screen, I get the whole table structure on the first line (so each of the above examples would be output on the first line (the actual table has about 100 entries in length)) and then from the second line I get a single entry per line (as shown above) which is what I want.  How can I ignore or NOT output the full structure on the first line?  And why do I get that?
2. I would like to transform the results shown above into a sqlite3 table structure which I would at a later date etl into a production mssql environment.   I have not been able to find a way to do this based on the output I am getting.

Comment: Have you read the [`sqlite3` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)? Also, why the encoding to a bytestring?

Comment: apologies for coming back to this late...   I have managed to sort it.   I can go into details if anyone is interested but the upshot is I am dragging in data from many sources and this was one structure of MANY...   But if needed I can backtrack and figure which scrape it was for and provide the solution I came up with.